# how to 'flush hosts' via ssh

Tags: mysql, ssh

I have a MySQL db hosted on a commercial server as a shared account. Recently I have been getting an error: 'DBI connect('xxxxxx',...) failed: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'.

However I can ssh into my host but trying to execute "mysqladmin flush-hosts' tells me 'DBI connect('xxx:example.com','xxxuserxxx',...) failed: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'".

My host cannot help me (outside their scope) but I am hoping there is a way either to escalate my privileges, or execute a mysqladmin command.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

What "users" exist in MySQL?  I hope you are not doing everything as `root` (or other `SUPER` user)!

Once you get past this problem, be sure to have a user that will let you get in, but is not being used otherwise for the application.

What I just said is good advice, but it may not be relevant to your symptom.  It seems that *your* host (at IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) has been pounding on the shared account.  Could this be?  Could it be that a hacker got into *your* host, and is using it to get at the hosted MySQL?

Is there another machine from which you could try to do the `FLUSH HOSTS`?